# using xargs to pass a variable to alias command

Tags: linux, bash, alias, xargs

I'm trying to write a one liner that creates an alias 'cd="cd dir_name"' which will change directory to to that dir_name

```
pwd | xargs -i alias cd{}='cd $PWD'
```

but I get:

```
xargs: alias: No such file or directory
```

is it that alias cannot be played with xargs or am I not using xargs correctly?

Comment: `xargs` is trying to execute the _command_ `alias`, but `alias` is a _builtin_.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to alias 'cd' to always cd into the present working directory? Could you explain in pseudo-code what this alias is meant to do?

Comment: `xargs` is run as a separate process; the shell it runs is also a separate process.  There's no way, even if you fix the invocation (e.g. `pwd | xargs -i bash -c "alias cd{}='cd $PWD'"`), that the result will be an alias in the current shell.  Your notation looks as though it might be trying to create `alias cd/home/you='cd /home/you'` which is dubious too.  You should probably use something like: `alias cd$(basename $PWD)="cd $PWD"`.

Answer (score 2):

`alias` is a shell builtin. `xargs` needs an external command to run. Normally, you can run a new shell in `xargs` to interpret the builtins or keywords:

```
pwd | xargs -i bash -c 'alias cd{}="cd $PWD"'
```

but it's useless in this case, as the alias would live only in the shell you run from `xargs`, not in the current one.

Moreover, alias can't be named `/home/user`. Maybe you meant

```
... alias cd='cd {}'
```

Use `pushd` and `popd` to remember the current directory and return to it later.